# WPF OpenFileDialog with http support?

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, http, openfiledialog

I want to copy past a http link into the OpenFileDialog. Unfortunately it looks like neither the Windows.Forms nor the Win32 OpenFileDialog does support http. 
Is there any way to add this functionality to these Dialogs or is there maybe a comparable OpenFileDialog which supports http? 
Thanks for help in advance.

Comment: Why not create your own window with single textbox? `OpenFileDialog` is completely different from what you ask, it is to select a file from your system which you can't do with http links

Comment: I want to use ONE dialog for both local and online files! And you can paste a http link into a every OpenFileDialog. Unfortunately the Win32 and Forms dialog does not parse it. 1to1

Comment: The funny thing is, when I paste my http url--> for excample http://orgmode.org/worg/org-tutorials/org-publish-html-tutorial.html the result in code (dialog.FileName) looks like this. C:\\Users\\User\\AppData\\Local\\Microsoft\\Windows\\INetCache\\IE\\AIC24HWI\\org-publish-html-tutorial[1].html . Maybe it is possible to reconstruct the original link from that ?